# mysql error message on stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I having some trouble with displaying the error message here's what I wrote:

```
     DELIMITER go
        Create procedure getusers(
         IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
             IN iPassword varchar(30))

        BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    -- this one is for checking the empty email address and it suppose to 
    -- display an error message.
        Select EmailAddress from users
        where not exists( select EmailAddress
        from users where EmailAddress=iEmailAddress
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
              SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Address does not exists';
        )

        End
        BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
-- this one is for checking the empty password and it suppose to 
    -- display an error message.
        Select Password from users
        where not exists( select Password
        from users where Password=iPassword
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
              SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Password does not exists';
        )

        End


        BEGIN
        Select EmailAddress, Password,Salt,RoleID,UserID from users
        where EmailAddress = iEmailAddress and PASSWORD = iPassword;
        End
        go
        DELIMITER ;
```

I got an error message that says:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
>         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Address does not ' at line 10"

I've used that link for references: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html

Comment: think you need a `;` at the end of each `SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'`. You usually need one at the end of lines in mysql procedures. Also check the position of the brackets - the closing bracket for the `exists` clause ought to be after the where clause I think, not after the `SET` statement?

Comment: There's quite a bit more wrong here in addition to syntax issues.  `EXIT HANDLER` is for **catching** exceptions, not **throwing** them, and the queries do not appear to be serving a meaningful purpose, both of them apparently scanning the entire table in the outer query (or, at best, being highly ambiguous).  What's the desired behavior here, exactly?

Comment: I've tried this DELIMITER go Create procedure getusers( IN iEmailAddress varchar(30)) BEGIN DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION Select EmailAddress from users where not exists( select EmailAddress from users where EmailAddress=iEmailAddress); BEGIN SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Address does not exist'; END; End go DELIMITER ; but when I tried call getusers('jeremy@gmail.com') it does not show error message but show the entire email address data instead

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and the solution is:

```
> DELIMITER go Create procedure getusers(  IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
> IN iPassword varchar(30)) BEGIN declare checkemailcount int; declare
> checkpasswordcount int;
> 
> select count(emailaddress) into checkemailcount from users where
> emailaddress = iEmailaddress;
> 
> select count(Password) into checkpasswordcount from users where
> Password = iPassword;
> 
> --check if emailaddress  not exists
> 
> If(checkemailcount!=1) then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT =
> 'Email address is not found';
> 
> --check if password not exists
> 
> Elseif (checkpasswordcount!=1) then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
> MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Password'; else
> 
>   select emailaddress,password,salt,UserID from users    where
> emailaddress=iEmailaddress and password = iPassword;
> 
> 
> End if; End go DELIMITER ;
```